# Resize iframe's inner content

Tags: html, css, iframe

It is a common question to resize an iframe to fit its' content, however I want instead to set the content to fit specific dimensions.

Essentially my application captures HTML, along with user_1's screen dimensions. So that user_2's sees the same HTML and screen dimensions.

In cases where user_1's screen dimensions are larger than user_2's screen dimensions, user_2 would see an iframe with a horizontal scrollbar. In cases where user_2's screen dimensions are smaller than user_2's screen dimensions, user_2 would see an iframe without a horizontal scrollbar and centred content.

Taking into account things like media queries where smaller screen resolutions add for instance a burger menu. I'd like for the second user to see the same thing.

What effectively I'd love to do is set the iframe's inner scrollWidth.

The only thing I've been able to suss out is that setting the actual width of the iframe itself is the best way to start. Then perhaps in cases where the content needs to expand beyond the width of the iframe, to set the width of the html or body element inside the iframe.

But that too, introduces media query issues. Where maybe the iframe on user_2's screen is small enough to trigger a burger menu, even though the body's width was set to expand beyond the iframe's width.

Is there any way I can set the iframe to be any width I want, but for the content of the iframe to behave as though the iframe was larger? I hope I've explained my problem in a way that makes sense.

I want user_2 to see the same thing user_1 saw.

Comment: Are you going for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/2k39q67k/

Comment: I'm starting to resign myself to the fact I'll probably need to wrangle with dual sets of scrollbars the same way you see them there. But yes, that is about exactly what I want.